# Mutual solubility of water and hexane

Tags: water, solutions, solubility

The question says that

> the value of mutual solubility of water and hexane is small. Consult bibliography to find it out.

I can't find it and I'm also concerned as to why the question doesn't include a temperature.

Comment: Obviously, because the said solubility is small at any temperature.

Comment: Sorry, what's the question?

Comment: A Google search for *hexane solubility in water* yields [this link](http://macro.lsu.edu/HowTo/solvents/hexane.htm) as the third result...

Comment: I have found this but my problem was that it said mutual solubility and as fas as I know, mutual solubility is the point where the two liquids are miscible. Anyway, thank you.